# JavaScript Appending another Div data on Div Tag Dynamically

Tags: javascript

I want to append the content of an already defined "old div" tag to the "new div" tag dynamically but its not working. The code i tried is attached below.
And one more question, how to remove that appended div tag dynamically?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function add() {

var i = document.getElementById( 'old' );
var d = document.getElementById( 'new' );
d.appendChild( i );
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="old">
Content of old div
</div>

<div id="new">
</div>
<button onclick="add()">Add</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It sure is a great idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ok I solved it. There was some error in my code. Its working now.

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function add() {

        var i = document.getElementById( 'old' );

        var d = document.createElement( 'div' );
        d.id = "new1";
        d.innerHTML = i.innerHTML ;
        var p = document.getElementById('new');

        p.appendChild(d);

    }

    function removeLocation() {

        var d = document.getElementById( 'new1' );

        var p = document.getElementById('new');

        p.removeChild(d);

    }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="old">
            Content of old div
        </div>

        <hr/>
        <div id="new">
        </div>
        <hr/>
        <button onclick="add();">Add</button><br>
        <button onclick="removeLocation();">Remove</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
var i = document.getElementById( 'old' );
var d = document.getElementById( 'new' );
d.innerHTML += i.innerHTML;
```

Comment: great.. you have made it much simple. I am voting for you. :-)

Comment: innerHTML is not a beautiful way to make it, so I recommend to use appendChild instead of it;)