# How to append div inside other div

Tags: jquery

I want to append div inside mytext div but it is updating text outside of the div

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
var jj= $('body').append('<div class="mytext">')
jj.append('<div>min</div>')
jj.append('</div>')
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316940/javascript-appending-another-div-data-on-div-tag-dynamically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jj refers to 'body' element.

```
$(function () {
    var $mydiv = $('<div>min</div>'),
        $body = $('body');
    $body.append('<div class="mytext">');
    var $mytext = $body.find('.mytext:last');
    $mytext.append($mydiv);
})
```

Comment: Because OP wants maybe to do more complex things

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
$(function(){
   var jj= $('body').append('<div class="mytext"></div>');
   $('.mytext').html('<div>min</div>')  ;     
 });
```

Comment: It does work, but you don't need to search through the DOM. `$('body').append('<div class="mytext"><div>min</div></div>')` is enough...

Comment: And @Ted where you found search on my code ,I just put .html to input the div with min...

Comment: come on @roasted, I'm not an oracle :), i just offered a solution for the particular piece if code...

Comment: @Gautam3164 - i was simply referring to `$('.mytext')`, your code works great, don't get worked up over nothing...

Comment: @Ted ya, and your solution works just like all others solution here... It's ok if you downvote and explain why, just as you did

Comment: But @Ted Its not wrong ans right...??So i dont think of downvote...even it is better much than your ans even

Answer (score 0):

you don't need jj

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('body').append('<div class="mytext"><div>min</div></div>')
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Comment: But @Ted Its not wrong ans right...??So i dont think of downvote...even it is better much than your ans even

Comment: @Gautam3164 - so in comparison, my answer deserves a downvote but yours doesn't? using your logic, they both work... so if i posted a solution that uses a loop and goes around the DOM 1000 times but still added one div into the other, i should get a +1...

Answer (score 0):

```
var myDiv = $('<div class="mytext"></div>');
myDiv.append('<div>min</div>');
$('body').append(myDiv);
```

The `append` function doesn't append html to the document. It appends elements to the document object tree.

You could, however, just write this on one line like this, if you wish.

```
$('body').append('<div class="mytext"><div>min</div></div>');
```

Boom.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    var jj= $('<div class="mytext"></div>');
    body.append(jj.append('<div>min</div>'));
});
```